# How to Insert and Update Preference Android Setting to MySQL Database

Tags: java, android, mysql, sharedpreferences, preferencefragment

I already created `preferenceFragment` to set `ScheduleSetting` for users, i have already created database and table `Schedules` which contain the following details :

- id
- user_id
- domicile
- days
- time_start
- time_end

How to insert values in java on android if empty and update if `user_id` has been saved already?

This is my Screenshoot but setting is currently saved on local device :

[image: SceduleSetting.xml]

Please help me i dont know what steps should be done and i have not found best practice for my case.

Thanks before.

Comment: No, my question is based on Java insert to Database MySQL.

Comment: @J.Chomel okey, sory my fault ... i will edit my question. Thanks :)